# Build ViewComponent in ViewModelBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I want to keep the building of a view's model inside its respective controller's view model builder(referred to from here on as a vmb). Using HomeController as an example, I will instantiate from its constructor HomeViewModelBuilder.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly HomeViewModelBuilder _viewModelBuilder;

    public HomeController(IUserManagerService userManagerService, IEmployeeService employeeService, IExampleServiceZ exampleServiceZ)
    {
       _viewModelBuilder = new HomeViewModelBuilder(userManagerService, employeeService, exampleServiceZ);
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _viewModelBuilder.BuildHomeViewModel(CurrentUserId);
        return View("Index", model);
    }
}
```

And to this vmb's constructor pass whatever services are needed to pull data from the repo.

Since .Net Core did not bring child actions along with it, I need to decide about how to continue with porting an asp.net mvc5 app. Some child action views call their own child actions. This isn't a question about nested view components, but rather, how to use a view component, keeping in mind that I want to do building in my builder. At the moment we are using a dirty hack with jquery like this:

The container on the view that will hold the child action

```
<div id="subsections-container">
    @*This is a place holder for the $.get*@
</div>
```

And at the bottom of the view is the script:

```
@section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var fieldsUrl = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Url.Action("Index", "SubSection")));

                $.get(fieldsUrl, { sectionId: @Model.Section.Id }, function (data) {
                    $("#subsections-container").html(data);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}
```

I would like to start using view components, but the example given by http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/01/02/goodbye-child-actions-hello-view-components.aspx

Included here

```
namespace MyWebApplication.ViewComponents
{
    public class WhatsNewViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private readonly IArticleService _articleService;

        public WhatsNewViewComponent(IArticleService articleService)
        {
            _articleService = articleService;
        }

        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int numberOfItems)
        {
            var articles = _articleService.GetNewArticles(numberOfItems);
            return View(articles);
        }
    }
}
```

he is building inside the invoke of that view component. I want to do that in the vmb.

The second issue is that I have an ajax form that wants to refresh the data in that container.

Form in the view:

```
@using (@Ajax.BeginForm("Update", "SubSection", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "subsections-container", OnBegin = "blockModal()", OnComplete = "hideModal();" }, new { id = "frm-subsection-update", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
}
```

The action hit in the subsection controller

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = RoleName.SubSectionUpdate)]
public ActionResult Update(SubsectionUpdateViewModel model)
{
    var subsection = new SubsectionDto();

    if (model.Id > 0)
        subsection = _subsectionService.Get(model.Id);

    subsection.InjectFrom(model);
    _subsectionService.Update(subsection);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { });
}
```

If this is no longer an action but a viewcomponent, what do I return here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> he is building inside the invoke of that view component. I want to do that in the vmb.

Add `WhatsNewViewComponentViewModel` property in `HomeViewModel` and give responsibility of creating `WhatsNewViewComponentViewModel` to `HomeViewModelBuilder`

In `Index.cshtml` of `Home` controller

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("WhatsNew",Model.WhatsNewViewComponentViewModel)
```

`WhatsNewViewComponent` :

```
public class WhatsNewViewComponent : ViewComponent
{  
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(WhatsNewViewComponentViewModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

> If this is no longer an action but a viewcomponent, what do I return here?

Return ViewComponent from Action

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = RoleName.SubSectionUpdate)]
public ActionResult Update(SubsectionUpdateViewModel model)
{
    .......
    return ViewComponent("VCName", VCModel);
}
```

Comment: My child action is in a different controller, so what I've done is declare and instantiate that controller's vmb in parent controller's vmb, so that in the builder method for Home/Index, I have SubsectionIndexViewComponent = _subsectionViewModelBuilder.BuildIndexViewModel(id)

Comment: Also, I assume that in the Update method that wants to return the view component, I will need to build the VCModel. Perhaps it would be better to build view component models in the respective view component then. Something for me to consider. Also, Re#er is recreating my view in Shared/Components, I would like it to stay in the relevant controller's views folder.

Comment: @AlanBall 1) building a VCModel in VC is good idea with respect to reusability too. 2) Create `~Views/Home/Components/WhatsNew/` folder and place `Default.cshtml` in it.